# Removed Ubuntu from Dual boot Win 10 - but which partitions can now be deleted?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, disk-management, dynamic-disk

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot alongside Windows 10. It failed, but I decided I wasn't that interested in Ubuntu anyway. I have now successfully removed the Ubuntu partition AND fixed the bootloader so that it's back to Windows.

There are 2 related problems :

1. There seem to be a number of leftover partitions from Ubuntu but I'm
   not sure which ones can be safely deleted and the space recovered. Even if I knew which ones to delete.
2. One of my disks is now listed as "dynamic" by Windows Disk Management - so I can do very little with it. Can't delete volumes, extend space etc. Research
   seems to suggest a third party tool such as Easeus can convert this
   back to a Basic disk - but is this what I need to do to recover the
   unutilised space?

The attached screenshot shows the partitions within Windows Disk Management.

[image: Disk Partions reported by windows]

Comment: If there is not any data you want in Disk 0, then you may clean that drive with `diskpart` command and start with making a new partition.

Answer (score 0):

For Disk0: Did you have Ubuntu on Disk0? I am guessing yes and that is represented by drive D:. Things to check:

1. Can you access any of the partitions on Disk0 besides the D: drive?
2. If not, do you see any space used via the disk or computer management panels? That will give you a clue if there is anything stored in those partitions.
3. I'm taking it that you tried the right click -> delete on the volume D and then the partitions? Once the volumes/partitions on Disk0 are deleted then you should have been able to right click on Disk0 and choose "Convert to Basic"

Here's the Microsoft doc on changing disk type: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk. From this it seems you can do it without a separate tool.

Comment: Ubuntu was on disk 0, the 500gb partition.
Disk manager doesn't offer any options on those three other volumes on disk 0. So it can't delete them and I can't convert to a basic disk. So I can't follow the Microsoft guide unfortunately. 

There's an option to extend on the D: drive, but that then fails saying weirdly insufficient space. There's masses of space on the D drive.

If I can delete those other partitions with a third party tool, is  there a risk they were somehow needed to boot windows? I can't figure out how to access them through windows.

Comment: You might have to re-format disk 0.  Ugly, but it does work.